# VSCode Language-Specific Background Color Like Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, visual-studio-code

I have recently moved to VSCode from using Notepad++ for many years. In Notepad++, if editing an HTML file for example, the default editor background is white, however it was able to colorize the background of different languages within the editor such as PHP and JavaScript between the opening and closing brackets. For example, any PHP code between  would have a light yellow background and JavaScript was light blue.

Is this possible in VSCode? This was extremely useful and a much missed feature since I moved to VSCode.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported out of the box as of VS Code 1.24. [This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20652) tracks per filetype themes

An extension could also hack something together to emulate this. See [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview) for getting started writing an extension

Comment: Thanks Matt for your quick response. I did see the posts about having filetype-based themes but that doesn't exactly address this particular concern. Hopefully an extension will be made available for this as more N++ people migrate across.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I found a solution by using the [Highlight extension](https://github.com/fabiospampinato/vscode-highlight) and a regular expression. Based on some of [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431312/extract-php-code-with-regular-expressions). Also relied on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to figure out what I'm doing. I don't use regular expressions much at all.

**Solution:**

After installing the Highlight extension, in my `settings.json` file, I have the following code to gently highlight PHP tags:

```
{
    // Other settings before...
    "highlight.regexes": {
        "(<\\?php.+?\\?>)": {  // match multiline php code between "<?php" and "?>"
            "regexFlags": "gims", // Flags used g (global), i (case insensitive), m (multiline), and s (single line [dotall])
            "filterLanguageRegex": "php", // Only applies to PHP files, optional
            "decorations": [ 
                { "backgroundColor": "#f2f2f2" },
            ]
        }
    }
    // Other settings after...
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I installed the extension and used the same settings config you had above but it didn't seem to do anything?

Comment: I'm certainly not an expert with VS Code yet, so it's hard to say.  I just switched to it last week. You could check the highlight color to make sure it's different enough to be visible.  Also, this regex is only targeting PHP, so if you're working with another language, you would need a separate regex rule for that.  Sorry, those are probably pretty unhelpful recommendations...

Comment: Also, just to be clear, there needs to be an opening/closing set of curly braces around all settings in settings.json (if you haven't already made changes in the file yet). I'll edit the answer above.

Comment: this option was the only problem sticking me to notepad++ and keeping away from vscode. great. thanks. and by the way, It's better to change the "(<\\?php.+?\\?>)" to "(<\\?.+?\\?>)" for php short tag :)

Comment: "backgroundColor": "#f2f2f2" >> "#fefcf5" for exactly the same as notepad++ :D

Comment: Thanks, @StudioX!  On a side note, since implementing this, I actually used an RGBA value for this.  I noticed there was a bit of an issue when selecting text, so I made it a semitransparent off-white color and that allowed the regular text selection color to show through a bit.