# Is there a way to change background color of syntax highlight in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-editor

I was looking for a better code editor for my projects and wanted to give VSCode a try. But I couldn't find where to customize the syntax highlighting settings. What I actually need is to change the background color of embedded languages within a file so that I can identify different parts of the code a lot easier.

I have this PHP file which contains, HTML, CSS and JavaScript and I'd like to set different background colors for all 4 languages within this single file. Is this possible with VSCode? or does anyone know a code editor that supports this? UltraEdit supports this but it has so many other shortcomings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode Language-Specific Background Color Like Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341018/vscode-language-specific-background-color-like-notepad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible [#3429 Themes don't support background styling](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3429)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex. Do you know a good programmer's editor that supports token background coloring?

Comment: Notepad++ has the ability to color embedded languages differently, including the background color. I've been using that for years, but like all code editors it has its shortcomings. It doesn't recognize the switch to SQL within PHP heredoc markers for example. It does give you what you are looking for in PHP with embedded HTML / JavaScript / Java / XML / ASP and VB script.